# Do we need to install apache & PHP if we use wordpress on docker?

Tags: docker

I am complete Docker newbie and just know that Docker are containers for running apps with all their dependencies however [Docker's Wordpress Page](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) shows additional installation of MariaDB to get it working.

As I understand containers (here wordpress) should have all it's basic dependencies i.e. PHP, APACHE, MYSQL out of the box, then why do we need to install Mariadb seperately?

Now that also leads me to another concern, whether I need to install APACHE & PHP too.

thanks
appu

Comment: why negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are meant to run one process each. In this case one would be Apache+PHP+Wordpress. A second process is the MySQL DB. So you would typically run this stack in two containers.

Comment: how would you define a "process" here? so can I then have 4 containers, one for each Wordpress component - 1 container for Apache, 1 for PHP, 1 for Wordpress, 1 for MySQL...?